# VMWare Fusion — Locked File after Power Cut

Tags: centos, mac-osx, vmware-fusion

After a power cut VMWare Fusion (under Mac OS X 10.5.7) shows that a CentOS 5 .vmx is locked.

[image: Screen Shot]

Clicking on the "padlock" brings up a dialogue with this message.

> **This virtual machine appears to be in use.**
>
> If this virtual machine is already in
>   use, press the "Cancel" button to
>   avoid damaging it. If this virtual
>   machine is not in use, press the "Take
>   Ownership" button to obtain ownership
>   of it.
>
> Configuration file:
>   /Users/rjstelling/Documents/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/CentOS 5 64-bit -
>   Development.vmwarevm/CentOS 5
>   64-bit.vmx

Clicking on "Take Ownership" fails, showing this message:

> **The virtual machine is in use by an application on your host computer.**
>
> Configuration file:
>   /Users/rjstelling/Documents/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/CentOS 5 64-bit -
>   Development.vmwarevm/CentOS 5
>   64-bit.vmx

I have no other VM software running. How can "unlock" this file and restart the VM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is step by step for a Mac:

1. Quit VMWare Fusion
2. Locate the VM file and right-click (or ctrl-click), select "Show Package Contents"
3. Move all the files and folders ending in .lck to the desktop
4. Restart VMWare Fusion
5. Restart the VM

*(6. If all goes well you can delete the .lck files and folders)*